# type helper and type request in one rspec test

Tags: rspec

Rails 5.2.2

When I need to add helper in my test I use type helper:

```
RSpec.describe Utilities, type: :helper do
end
```

When I need to add some request like pach or delete or post I use type request:

```
RSpec.describe 'AuthenticationPages', type: 
:request do
end
```

But when I need to use type helper and request together, what is should  be code?

for sample code :

```
  RSpec.describe Utilities, type: :helper do
  describe 'as wrong user' do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    let(:wrong_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: 'wrong@example.com')}
    before {sign_in user, no_capybara: true}

    describe 'submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action' do
       before {get edit_user_path(wrong_user)}
      specify {expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user'))}
       specify {expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RSpec.describe 'AuthenticationPages', type: :request do
  describe Utilities, type: :helper do

//it's work 

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `type` is just a piece of metadata, you can read more about it on the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure#standard-rails-specs-must-specify-the-%60:type%60-metadata). When using Rails and Rspec the type is automatically inferred loading extra goodies to simplify test writing.

From what I understand there is no way to provide a list of types or something similar so you have a few options.

**Option 1**: pick a type for your spec, load what you need from the other type manually.

**Option 2**: create a new specialized type, load all you need just for that one, short example extracted from `rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include JsonHelpers, type: :my_unique_type
  # ...
end
```

In this case if one marks a spec with `type: :my_unique_type`, `JsonHelpers` will be loaded and available inside that spec.

**Option 3**: Split responsibilities so you don't need both types, test the helper separately from the request test.

Comment: Can I ask you additional about Option 2. I opened file rails_helper.rb and actually, there is this sample code.

Comment: @OlegShevtsov what's the question?

Comment: My previous question isn't full. But I get solution another way, like :RSpec.describe 'AuthenticationPages', type: :request do
describe Utilities, type: :helper do

//it's work 

end
end